# facebook SDK appcompant unity3D Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-appcompat, facebook-unity-sdk

Unity crashing when I try to get build with facebook sdk.
I try to get Android Studio export to fix issue but its not work too.
its start when I add appcompat-v7-25.3.1 to project.
I have appodeal sdk . imported to the project.
so any one can help me to fix this issue.

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/enes/Library/Android/sdk1/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "/Users/enes/Library/Android/sdk1/platforms/android-26/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.android.vending.billing:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.kochava.base:com.appodeal.adcolony.unity:com.facebook.ads:io.fabric.answers.android.unity:android.support.v7.appcompat:com.appodeal.applovin.unity:com.appodeal.ads.unity:io.fabric.beta.android.unity:com.appodeal.chartboost.unity:com.unity.purchasing:io.fabric.crashlytics.android.unity:io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.android.crashlyticswrapper:com.google.android.exoplayer2:io.fabric.sdk.android.unity:io.fabric.unity.android.fabricinit:com.appodeal.facebook.unity:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.appodeal.inmobi.unity:com.appodeal.mailru.unity:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.analytics:com.google.android.gms.analytics:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.location:com.google.android.gms.safetynet:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.appodeal.presage.unity:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.v4:tr.com.fugo.wordtower.resources:com.appodeal.unityads.unity:com.appodeal.yandexmetrica.unity -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GoogleAIDL/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GooglePlay/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/KochavaTracker/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/ads-release/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/common/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/fabric/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-lite-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-analytics-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-analytics-impl-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-base-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-basement-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-clearcut-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-gass-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-location-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-safetynet-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-tasks-11.0.4/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-compat-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-ui-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-utils-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-fragment-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4-25.3.1/res" -S "/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unity-android-resources/res"

stderr[
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <ImageView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:scrollIndicators from <ScrollView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:36: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:24: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:59: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <ImageView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <view>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/abc_select_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/abc_select_dialog_material for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml:16: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml:74: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml:74: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml:57: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml:57: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/exo_playback_control_view for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action.xml:32: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/notification_action for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml:37: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout/notification_action_tombstone.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/notification_action_tombstone for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:89: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:56: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <FrameLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <FrameLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <FrameLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_custom.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource tr.com.fugo.wordtower:layout/notification_template_big_media_custom for configuration v17.
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
/Users/enes/WordeXtra/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/appcompat-v7-25.3.1/res/layout-v11/notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes;
```